# What is splunk xml option name

Tags: xml, splunk

This is my first time using `splunk` and xml. I have some queries I need to clarify. What does the option name refer to? How do I change the default settings of the chart? Please provide me with some tutorial or example.

```
<row>
    <chart>
        <searchTemplate>
            index="sdf" source="skype" username="$username$" | timechart count by username
        </searchTemplate>
        <title>Skype access over time</title>
        <option name="charting.chart">line</option>
        <option name="count">10</option>
        <option name="displayRowNumbers">true</option>
        <option name="charting.primaryAxisTitle.text">Time</option>
        <option name="charting.secondaryAxisTitle.text">Skype Activity</option>
    </chart>
</row>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks to be the "Simple XML" format for dashboards. (Instead of the "Advanced XML") the `option` element is how you can set and tweak all sorts of display options for your chart. Splunk has very comprehensive documentation on [all of the option names for `chart`](http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/Viz/ChartConfigurationReference) as well as for [all of the other Simple XML elements that can be used](http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/Viz/PanelreferenceforSimplifiedXML) and the same manual has how to docs for building dashboards using the UI and Simple XML as well.